# Under what conditions on $p$ and $q$, the integers $a$ and $b$ have a common prime divisor

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, gcd-and-lcm

Let us consider a formula of the form:

$$a=(p/q)b$$
where $a, p,q,b$ are positive integers such that $p$ and $q$ are coprime.

My **question** is: Under what conditions on $p$ and $q$ do the integers $a$ and $b$ have a common prime divisor?

Comment: Sorry, ignore the previous comment - it was made in haste. What I wanted to mean was that you have $a/p = b/q$ where both sides are integers (can you see why?). Can you now finish off the problem from here ?

Comment: @rah4927: Still not unerstood where you mean.

Comment: The above equation implies that unless $a=p$ and $b=q$, you'll always have $\gcd(a,b)>1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection between the values of $p$ and $q$ and the common factors of $a$ and $b$. This is because for any given coprime $p,q$ we can choose any number $r$ and set $a=pr$, $b=qr$. This gives a solution where $\gcd(a,b)=r$, so for any $p,q$ we can get any gcd we want.